# Wrong argument type for NSAssert1

Tags: objective-c, long-integer, short, upcasting

This isn't giving me an error but several warnings I'd like to get rid of.

```
OSErr err = AudioUnitInitialize(toneUnit);
NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error initializing unit: %ld", err);
```

The warning I'm getting is: `Format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'OSErr' (aka 'short')`. Obviously I can change this by using `long` instead of `OSErr` but I was wondering why I'm getting the error. This is an upcast so I thought it shouldn't cause any problems.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: just a heads up - dont use NSAssert1, NSAssert2 etc. Just use NSAssert

Comment: Why not, what's the difference?

Comment: You don't have to.. but NSAssert1, NSAssert2 etc are the legacy asserts from before NSAssert could handle any number of arguments (@dasblinkenlight is wrong - NSAssert1 isn't a variadic function). Would you prefer NSLog1(), NSLog2(), etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `NSAssert1` is a [*variadic function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D) implemented within the constraints of C, it cannot perform the cast internally: it is not possible to find the type of an argument passed in the vararg section of the function. Objective-C compiler will perform the default type promotions before making the call, but the `short` is converted to `int`, not to `long` by default. That is why you should either insert an explicit cast, or use a different format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error initializing unit: %hd", err);
```

or

```
NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error initializing unit: %ld", (long)err);
```

instead.